# Multiple array except in PySpark

Tags: arrays, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark dataframe:

```
> numbers_df
+----+-----------+-----------+-----------+-------------------------------------+
| id |      num_1|      num_2|      num_3|                              all_num|
+----+-----------+-----------+-----------+-------------------------------------+
|   1|  [1, 2, 5]|     [4, 7]|     [8, 3]|          [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]|
|   2|   [12, 13]|   [10, 20]|   [15, 17]| [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]|
+----+-----------+-----------+-----------+-------------------------------------+
```

I need to except from column `all_num` values of `num_1`, `num_2` and `num_3` columns.
Expected result:

| id | num_1 | num_2 | num_3 | all_num | except_num |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | [1, 2, 5] | [4, 7] | [8, 3] | [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] | [6, 9] |
| 2 | [12, 13] | [10, 16] | [15, 17] | [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18] | [11, 14, 18] |

How can this be done in PySpark? Since `array_except` function takes only two columns as input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine `array_except` and `concat` functions.

```
df = df.withColumn('except_num', F.array_except('all_num', F.concat('num_1', 'num_2', 'num_3')))
df.show(truncate=False)
```